# How can we create html and css of a component in given image

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

How can we create html and css of a overlay component in given below image.

[image]

In this image I have marked the portion.

I have gone through with this. I have tried to create that model but no able to create exact as given in image. I tried with border-top-left-radius, border-top-right-radius,border-bottom-right-radius,border-bottom-left-radius

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
}

.image {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  border-radius: 50%
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 30%;
  margin-top: 250px;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: .5s ease;
  background-color: #008CBA;
}

.container:hover .overlay {
  opacity: 1;
}

.text {
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Fade in Overlay</h2>
<p>Hover over the image to see the effect.</p>

<div class="container">
  <img src="img_avatar.png" alt="Avatar" class="image">
  <div class="overlay">
    <div class="text">Hello World</div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Make the green circle with the letter S into a a div. Create another div for the black part with the word Change. Then put both these divs into a parent div. Make the parent relative and position the change div absolutely to ur exact position.

Comment: To get a circle you need the height and width of the element to be the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here  is an example:

```css
.wrapper {
    position: relative;
}
.dot {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: #33473b;
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  }
.overlay {
  height: 40px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: #233028;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <span class="dot">
    <div class="overlay">foo</div>
  </span>
</div>
```

Just give the circle an "overlay" and set the overflow of the circe to hidden.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my attempt, also when you go hover with cursor on the image shows the "change" overlay part. It's possible to set a `backgroud-image` to the profile-pic element or also put an image inside it.

```css
.profile-pic {

  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  position: relative;
  background: gray;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 100ms ease-in-out;
}

.profile-pic img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
}

.change {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 6px 0;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
  font-size: 14px;
  transition: all 100ms ease-in-out;
}

.profile-pic:hover .change {
  opacity: 1;
}
 
.css-bg {
  background-image: url('http://placekitten.com/200/200');
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="profile-pic">
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/100/100" />
  <div class="change">
    Change
  </div>
</div>

<br>
<br>

<div class="profile-pic css-bg">
  <div class="change">
    Change
  </div>
</div>
```